# Switch user without creating an intermediate process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec, sudo

I'm able to use `sudo` or `su` to execute a command as another user. By combining with `exec`, I'm able to replace the current process with `sudo` or `su`, and a child process running the command. But I want to replace the current process with the command running as another user. How do I do that?

Testing with `sleep inf` as the command, and `someguy` as the user:

```
exec su someguy -c 'sleep inf'
```

This gives me from `pstree`:

```
bash───su───sleep
```

And

```
exec sudo -u someguy sleep inf
```

gives

```
bash───sudo───sleep
```

In both cases I just want the `sleep` command, with `bash` as the parent.

I expect I could do this from C with something some sequence of `setuid()` and `exec()`.

Comment: Currently the bash gets replaces by `su` or `sudo` and it runs a child `sleep`. You want `bash` and `sleep` as child of bash?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I want bash--sleep.

Comment: See if the answer I posted helps. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between `sudo sleep` and `exec sudo sleep` is that in the second command sudo process replaces bash image and calling shell process exits when sleep exits

```
pstree -p $$
bash(8765)───pstree(8943)

((sleep 1; pstree -p $$ )&); sudo -u user sleep 2
bash(8765)───sudo(8897)───sleep(8899)

((sleep 1; pstree -p $$ )&); exec sudo -u user sleep 2
sudo(8765)───sleep(8993)
```

however the fact that `sudo` or `su` fork a new process depends on design and their implementation (some sources found [here](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/tip/src)).

From sudo man page :

> Process model
>
> When sudo runs a command, it calls fork(2), sets up the execution environment as described above, and calls the execve system call in the child process.  The main sudo
>       process waits until the command has completed, then passes the command's exit status to the security policy's close function and exits.  If an I/O logging plugin is config-
>        ured or if the security policy explicitly requests it, a new  pseudo-terminal (“pty”) is created and a second sudo process is used to relay job control signals between the
>        user's existing pty and the new pty the command is being run in.  This extra process makes it possible to, for example, suspend and resume the command.  Without it, the com-
>        mand would be in what POSIX terms an “orphaned process group” and it would not receive any job control signals.  As a special case, if the policy plugin does not define a
>        close function and no pty is required, sudo will execute the command directly instead of calling fork(2) first.  The sudoers policy plugin will only define a close function
>        when I/O logging is enabled, a pty is required, or the pam_session or pam_setcred options are enabled.  Note that pam_session and pam_setcred are enabled by default on sys-
>        tems using PAM.

Comment: It would seem something in the sudo code is preventing it from execing directly. If you know how to ensure this behaviour, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I do not share the observation and the conclusions. See below:

I created two shellscripts:

```
$ cat just_sudo.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo sleep inf
$ cat exec_sudo.sh
#!/bin/bash
exec sudo sleep inf
```

So, one with an exec, one without. If I do a `pstree` to see the starting situation, I get:

```
$ pstree $$
bash───pstree
$ echo $$
17250
```

This gives me the baseline. Next I launched both scripts:

```
$ bash just_sudo.sh &
[1] 1218
$ bash exec_sudo.sh &
[2] 1220
```

And then, `pstree` gives:

```
$ pstree $$
bash─┬─bash───sleep
     ├─pstree
     └─sleep
```

the first being the `just_sudo`, the second is the `exec_sudo`.  Both run as root:

```
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
root      1219  1218  0 14:01 pts/4    00:00:00 sleep inf
root      1220 17250  0 14:01 pts/4    00:00:00 sleep inf
```

once again the first is the `just_sudo` and the second the `exec_sudo`. You can see that the parent-PID for the sleep in the `exec_sudo` is the interactive shell from which the scripts are launched and the PID is 1220, which was the PID we saw when the script was launched in the background.

If you use two terminal windows and do not put it in the background, this will work also:

```
terminal 1                            terminal 2
$ echo $$
16053                                 $ pstree 16053
                                      bash
$ sudo sleep inf
                                      $ pstree 16053
                                      bash───sleep
^C
$ exec sudo sleep inf
                                      $ pstree 16053
                                      sleep
^C
 ( window is closed )
```

So, on *my* linux system, the behavior is not as you suggest.The only way that the sudo may remain in the process-tree is if it runs in the existing tty (so without an exec), or if it is invoked with a pseudo-terminal, for example as `exec sudoedit`.

Comment: Your answer is a little short of receiving an upvote from me. The reason that your observations and conclusions differ from those of the author of the question is because you run your `*_sudo.sh` scripts in the background (with the `&` character at the end of the command line). The explanation for it can be found in the source code - see https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/tip/src/exec.c and pay attention to the fragment of the code marked with a comment containing *just exec directly*). Improve your answer using the provided info and you will receive an upvote from me.

Comment: the running in the background is not a reason, as demonstrated by running in a differnt terminal. The code states that a direct exec is only not done is there is an I/O plugin or the policy has requested a pty. This is in general only the case if you invoke `sudoedit`. Otherwise you have to do something very special.

Comment: I don't get the behaviour you describe with your exec_sudo.sh.

Comment: @LjmDullaart what is your OS? I think it's highly implementation defined.

Comment: It's all Linux. Fedora 23, Slackware 14.2 (both 64 bit) and Raspian Jessie.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this can be done using `sudo` or `su`. But you can easily achieve this using a simple `c` program. I will be showing a very bare minimal one with hard coded command and user id, but you can always customize it to your liking

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

 int runAs(int gid, int uid, char *command[]) {
    setgid(gid);
    setuid(uid);
    char *args[]={"sleep","inf",NULL};
    execvp(args[0],args);
 }


 int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
 {
     runAs(1000, 65534, argv);
     return 0;
 }
```

> Note: on my machine `1000` is the uid/gid of `vagrant` user and group. `65534` is uid and gid of `nobody` user and group

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo gcc test.c -o sosu
sudo chown root:root sosu
sudo chmod u+s sosu
```

Now time for a test

```
$ pstree $$ -p
bash(23251)───pstree(28627)

$ ./sosu
```

Now from another terminal

```
$ pstree -p 23251
bash(23251)───sleep(28687)

$ ps aux | grep [2]8687
nobody   28687  0.0  0.0   7288   700 pts/0    S+   11:40   0:00 sleep inf
```

As you can see the process is run as `nobody` and its a child of `bash`

Comment: This might end up being necessary I think.

Comment: My suggestion is that if anyone wishes to use `argv` for the new command, try `argv++`, followed by `execvp(*argv, argv)`. The vector `argv` itself is exactly what `execv*()` functions need. Don't forget to check if `argc == 1` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

## In order to free a command, you have to give him *std io*:

For this,you could either close all *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* or let them point elsewhere.

Try this:

```
su - someguy -c 'exec nohup sleep 60 >/tmp/sleep.log 2>/tmp/sleep.err <<<"" &'
```

Note:

```
su - someguy -c 'exec nohup sleep 60 &'
```

Is enough, and

```
su - someguy -c 'exec sleep 60 >/tmp/sleep.log 2>/tmp/sleep.err <<<"" &'
```

Will work too.

Consider having a look at `man nohup`

Note 2: Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use:

```
su - someguy -c 'exec sleep 60 & disown -h'
```

... And read `help disown` or `man bash`.

### Little demo showing how to *close* all IOs:

```
su - someguy -c 'exec 0<&- ; exec 1>&- ; exec 2>&- ; exec sleep 60 &'
```

#### quick test:

```
pstree $(ps -C sleep ho pid)
sleep
```

Comment: This is no good because you're detaching the sleep process and it's being reparented onto init. I need sleep to be a child of the bash process that originally invoked su or sudo.